# Run query where column = *

Tags: google-sheets

Need to run a query on google sheets where the column match any(*) value. I'm doing this because the criteria is filled by refering to another cell (like a filter).
Probably I'm missing something in the syntax.

My last try:

```
=QUERY(PROD!A:U;"SELECT L, SUM(M), SUM(O), SUM(Q), (1-(SUM(Q)/SUM(O))) 
WHERE T = '*' AND D = '*' AND U = '*' 
GROUP BY L 
ORDER BY SUM(M) DESC 
LABEL L 'PRODUTO', SUM(M) 'QUANTIDADE', SUM(Q) 'CUSTO', SUM(O) 'VENDA', (1-(SUM(Q)/SUM(O))) 'MARK-UP'")
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Is * a placeholder or should * be within the string?

Comment: I'm literally writing the *, passing it within the string. As we do on MySQL and SQL, for exemple.

Comment: I don't get any issues when filtering for columns ='*'. What error are you getting?

Comment: The query return nothing, there's no error when I write the query like this `column = '*'` (with the single quote). But I guess the query is looking for * caracter in the column and not anything.

Comment: Do you want the column not to be blank? If so you can just use <> ''

Comment: Thank you so much @RobinGertenbach you pointed the right direction. I had to use both `is not null` and `<> ''` to achieve what I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [Google Visualization API Query Language](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage) (not to be confused with T-SQL, MySQL, etc) the clause `WHERE T = '*'` means that the content of column T is literally the string `*`.

To test for a cell being nonempty, use `T <> ''` (for text columns) or `T is not null` (for numeric columns).

There are also [`like` and  `matches`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#Where) for more complex text filtering.